# How to deal with target name conflicts between Mercurial repositories and subrepositories?

Tags: cmake, mercurial, subrepos

My Mercurial repository repo1 has a custom target named `foo`; never mind what it does. I also have another repository repo2, which which I want to use as a subrepo of repo1. repo2 is developed in a similar fashion to repo1, and  also has a custom target named `foo`, doing about the same thing (but just for the repo2 directory of course).

If I try to run CMake for repo1 with `add_subdirectory(relative/path/to/repo2)` in the `CMakeLists.txt`, I get:

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:123 (add_custom_target):
  add_custom_target cannot create target "foo" because another target with
  the same name already exists.  The existing target is a custom target
  created in source directory
```

I suppose I could just prefix the custom target names with the repository names, but that seems like a crude solution to this problem; and I kind of like the fact that `make foo` does the same thing, conceptually, both in repo1 and in repo2. So is there anything smarter I can do here?

Comment: `I kind of like the fact that 'make foo' does the same thing, conceptually, both in repo1 and in repo2.` - And what behavior of `make foo` in repo1 you expect? Building `foo` in both repo1 and repo2? Or building only `foo` in repo1? If you want the last case, instead of `add_subdirectory` use `ExternalProject_Add`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: I don't mind very much which option it is, actually (also, in some cases this might be the same thing, e.g. if `foo` is something like running `cloc` or `ctags`). But other people reading this question may have either preference. Can you make your suggestion into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach depends on what you expect from

```
make foo
```

1. Building target only for **current project**. That is, being run from directory of project1, `make foo` should build target for this project. Same for project2.

   In that case, use `ExternalProject_Add` instead of `add_subdirectory` for bind projects together.
2. Building targets for **both projects**.

   Usually such targets are "project-wide actions", like `make uninstall` or `make test`.

   In that case, before adding the target into the project, you need to check whether target exists and take appropriate actions:

   ```
   if(NOT TARGET foo)
       <create target foo>
   endif()
   <append-new-actions-to-foo>
   ```

   Steps "create" and "append" depend on target type.

   E.g., classic `uninstall` target automatically process all subprojects via reading `install_manifest.txt` file:

   ```
   if(NOT TARGET uninstall)
       add_custom_target(uninstall ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/cmake_uninstall.cmake)
   endif()
   ```

   For general case, you may create *per-project targets* and attach them via `add_dependencies` to the "shared" target:

   ```
   if(NOT TARGET foo)
       add_custom_target(foo)
   endif()
   add_custom_target(foo_${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} <do-something>)
   add_dependencies(foo foo_${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME})
   ```

Comment: I like your second option a lot. The first option could use a link or some more explanation but this is enough for me to accept.